# sharepoint list version history export to excel

Tags: sharepoint, version-control, export

Good day !

I need to do the export versions of the log data item in the excel.
 [This solution](http://mosshistoryexport.codeplex.com/) I unfortunately cannot use because I'm from Russia, and the solution only supports the Latin alphabet.
 so I have the most to learn to extract data from the version history for a single item list.

please help. how is this done?

Comment: check this script on TechNet [Export the Version Comments and Version Details for each Document in SharePoint](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Get-the-Version-Comments-4c82dac4)

Answer (score 10):

While I haven't found a clean way of doing this, I have a partial workaround.

1. Use the Export to Excel option in the List section of the ribbon (make sure the list view you export includes a modified column - thanks T6J2E5).
2. Save the owssvr.iqy file and open with notepad
3. Copy just the URL from the file and paste it back into your browser, adding "&IncludeVersions=TRUE"
4. Save the XML file and open in Excel (or your favorite XML viewer), selecting the "As an XML table" open option.
5. You'll have to delete the first few columns and rows as they contain the schema data but other than that you should have all the version history (I suggest you add the Version column to the view). You can sort by the Modified column to get a chronological change log of the entire list.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I still manage to get only the latest version

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. Thanks! When you do this, make sure the list view you export includes a **modified** column. Then, after you open the XML file, you can sort the spreadsheet by the **modified** column to get a chronological change log of the entire list.

Comment: Re: `Copy just the URL from the file`, in my export file, I cannot see a URL value, there is a path column, but it has no file extension etc (edit: actually I opened the file in excel, but the steps said to open in notepad, maybe it is visible there).    Where should the URL be?  Also, as it is somewhat related, does anyone know if version settings are configured to keep the last, say, 10 versions, does that mean it is only possible to append to a field ten times?  If so, what happens after then 10th appending action?  Does it delete the earliest appended text?

Answer (score 1):

FYI "IncludeVersions=TRUE" should be before the List ID for anyone else that needs this.
spurl/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&IncludeVersions=TRUE&List={ListID}&View={VIEWID}&RowLimit=0&RootFolder=name

I am facing Error after doing the same that semicolon is missing. how to resolve it.