# Extract Version History from word documents in sharepoint folder and export the list into excel

Tags: excel, powershell, sharepoint, ms-word, power-automate

Extract Version History for word documents in SharePoint folder and exporting as excel.

I have more than 50-word documents enlisted as SharePoint list in a folder. I wanted to extract all the list from share point to excel with version history. I can extract the data as excel file but without version history.

I wanted to get excel file with version history which contains columns (modified time, modified by, comments) from every word document in that folder.

I tried power automate and online SharePoint online to get the data but It failed. I tried with power shell too.

Comment: PowerAutomate failed how? We’re not going to build the solution for you, I suggest you show something that we can work on fixing for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here are different ways you could do this:

- There is a PowerShell script called "SPDocVersion-Exporter" that can export the document version history details for all documents in a specific SharePoint Document Library to an Excel/CSV file. https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/export-sharepoint-version-history-to-excel/
- Use the SharePoint API call to retrieve version history. Once you have the data, you can use standard Flow Excel actions to write to an Excel workbook. https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Extract-Sharepoint-List-Version-History/td-p/175035
- Finally you can save the `owssvr.iqy` file and open it with Notepad. You can copy just the URL from the file and paste it back into your browser, adding `&IncludeVersions=TRUE`. [sharepoint list version history export to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10561661/sharepoint-list-version-history-export-to-excel)

Let me know if any of these help.